# how to google cloud pub/sub ignore message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I made a crawler. Crawler is executed when api is called through pub/sub push event.

my crawler is work like this

1. publish event ( message contain crawling site A )

-->

2. crawing site A API is called ( task name is task_A )

-->

3. publish event again ( message contain crawling site A )

-->

4. The above event is ignored. Because the message corresponding to operation 1 has not been acked yet.

number 4 is action i want

how to implement it ?

Comment: Do you want the second event to be processed after the first event or do you want it not to be processed at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some attributes to the pubsub message to indicate whether such message should be received. Then use **Subscription filter** of PubSub to specify what messages you want.